# How do you properly extend Material UI button in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Almost everything works here except props aren't getting passed through correctly. I'm new to TypeScript so I know I'm definitely getting some stuff wrong here. Just can't quite get it sorted out.

**Custom Link Button Attempt 1**

```js
const LoginSignupButton = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: rgba(Colors.white, 0.5),
    backgroundColor: rgba(Colors.white, 0.05),
    "&:hover": {
      color: rgba(Colors.white, 0.75),
      backgroundColor: rgba(Colors.white, 0.2)
    }
  }
})(Button);

export default LoginSignupButton;
```

**Usage 1**

```js
<LoginSignupButton component={Link} to={"/register"} fullWidth>
  Sign up for a free trial
</LoginSignupButton>
```

**Error 1**

```js
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Pick<DefaultComponentProps<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<{ props: { color?: "inherit" | "default" | "primary" | "secondary" | undefined; disableFocusRipple?: boolean | undefined; endIcon?: ReactNode; fullWidth?: boolean | undefined; href?: string | undefined; size?: "medium" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; startIcon?: ReactNode; variant?: "text" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; }; defaultComponent: "button"; classKey: ButtonClassKey; }>>>, "title" | ... 281 more ... | "variant"> & StyledComponentProps<...>, context?: any): ReactElement<...> | ... 1 more ... | null', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: string; component: OverridableComponent<LinkTypeMap<{}, "a">>; to: string; className: string; fullWidth: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<DefaultComponentProps<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<{ props: { color?: "inherit" | "default" | "primary" | "secondary" | undefined; disableFocusRipple?: boolean | undefined; endIcon?: ReactNode; fullWidth?: boolean | undefined; href?: string | undefined; size?: "medium" |...'.
      Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<DefaultComponentProps<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<{ props: { color?: "inherit" | "default" | "primary" | "secondary" | undefined; disableFocusRipple?: boolean | undefined; endIcon?: ReactNode; fullWidth?: boolean | undefined; href?: string | undefined; size?: "medium" |...'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: PropsWithChildren<Pick<DefaultComponentProps<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<{ props: { color?: "inherit" | "default" | "primary" | "secondary" | undefined; disableFocusRipple?: boolean | undefined; endIcon?: ReactNode; fullWidth?: boolean | undefined; href?: string | undefined; size?: "medium" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; startIcon?: ReactNode; variant?: "text" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; }; defaultComponent: "button"; classKey: ButtonClassKey; }>>>, "title" | ... 281 more ... | "variant"> & StyledComponentProps<...>>, context?: any): ReactElement<...> | ... 1 more ... | null', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: string; component: OverridableComponent<LinkTypeMap<{}, "a">>; to: string; className: string; fullWidth: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<DefaultComponentProps<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<{ props: { color?: "inherit" | "default" | "primary" | "secondary" | undefined; disableFocusRipple?: boolean | undefined; endIcon?: ReactNode; fullWidth?: boolean | undefined; href?: string | undefined; size?: "medium" |...'.
      Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<DefaultComponentProps<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<{ props: { color?: "inherit" | "default" | "primary" | "secondary" | undefined; disableFocusRipple?: boolean | undefined; endIcon?: ReactNode; fullWidth?: boolean | undefined; href?: string | undefined; size?: "medium" |...'.
```

**Custom Link Button Attempt 2**

```js
class LinkButton extends React.Component<ButtonProps & LinkProps> {
  public render() {
    return <Button component={Link} {...this.props} />;
  }
}

const LoginSignupButton = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: rgba(Colors.white, 0.5),
    backgroundColor: rgba(Colors.white, 0.05),
    "&:hover": {
      color: rgba(Colors.white, 0.75),
      backgroundColor: rgba(Colors.white, 0.2)
    }
  }
})(LinkButton);

export default LoginSignupButton;
```

**Usage 2**

```js
<LoginSignupButton to={"/register"} fullWidth>
  Sign up for a free trial
</LoginSignupButton>
```

**Error 2**

```js
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Pick<{ action?: ((instance: ButtonBaseActions | null) => void) | RefObject<ButtonBaseActions> | null | undefined; buttonRef?: ((instance: unknown) => void) | RefObject<unknown> | null | undefined; ... 7 more ...; TouchRippleProps?: Partial<...> | undefined; } & ... 7 more ... & Pick<...>, "color" | ... 296 more ... | "TypographyClasses"> & StyledComponentProps<...>, context?: any): ReactElement<...> | ... 1 more ... | null', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: string; to: string; className: string; fullWidth: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<{ action?: ((instance: ButtonBaseActions | null) => void) | RefObject<ButtonBaseActions> | null | undefined; buttonRef?: ((instance: unknown) => void) | RefObject<...> | null | undefined; ... 7 more ...; TouchRippleProps?: Partial<...> | undefined; } & ... 7 more ... & Pick<...>, "color" |...'.
      Property 'to' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<{ action?: ((instance: ButtonBaseActions | null) => void) | RefObject<ButtonBaseActions> | null | undefined; buttonRef?: ((instance: unknown) => void) | RefObject<...> | null | undefined; ... 7 more ...; TouchRippleProps?: Partial<...> | undefined; } & ... 7 more ... & Pick<...>, "color" |...'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(props: PropsWithChildren<Pick<{ action?: ((instance: ButtonBaseActions | null) => void) | RefObject<ButtonBaseActions> | null | undefined; buttonRef?: ((instance: unknown) => void) | RefObject<unknown> | null | undefined; ... 7 more ...; TouchRippleProps?: Partial<...> | undefined; } & ... 7 more ... & Pick<...>, "color" | ... 296 more ... | "TypographyClasses"> & StyledComponentProps<...>>, context?: any): ReactElement<...> | ... 1 more ... | null', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: string; to: string; className: string; fullWidth: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<{ action?: ((instance: ButtonBaseActions | null) => void) | RefObject<ButtonBaseActions> | null | undefined; buttonRef?: ((instance: unknown) => void) | RefObject<...> | null | undefined; ... 7 more ...; TouchRippleProps?: Partial<...> | undefined; } & ... 7 more ... & Pick<...>, "color" |...'.
      Property 'to' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<{ action?: ((instance: ButtonBaseActions | null) => void) | RefObject<ButtonBaseActions> | null | undefined; buttonRef?: ((instance: unknown) => void) | RefObject<...> | null | undefined; ... 7 more ...; TouchRippleProps?: Partial<...> | undefined; } & ... 7 more ... & Pick<...>, "color" |...'.
```

Either way the error is similar. I just can't figure out how to take care of it as I'm still pretty new to TypeScript.

Comment: You tried to set 'component' property and it was not declared 
and existed in  1 attempt.

Comment: In example 1 in expecting the props to be passed to Button